# Allow certain endpoint unauthenticated access in spring resource server

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have setup a spring resource server using Spring 5. All my endpoints now require a valid access token. How can I allow my /health endpoint free access? With below configuration, it does not work and health endpoint also requires an access token.

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user").authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
            .and().requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I added this small piece of code to make it work like a charm.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/user");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anonymous disabled somewhere? You should also switch to the new way of defineing web security: provide a `SecurityFilterChain` @Bean instead of extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. This is the recomanded way since something like 2.4 and will be the only way from 3.0 (released next month)

Comment: Hi ch4mp, yes I don't have anonymous disabled. Thanks for your recommendation and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is anonymous enabled?

```java
http.anonymous().and().authorizeRequests()...
```

Side note, `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated. Instead of extending it, you should provide your application context with a `SecurityFilterChain` @Bean:

```java
@Bean public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http.anonymous().and().authorizeRequests()...

    return http.build();
}
```